# How do you get Material-UI Tabs to work with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to get Material-UI tabs to work with routing, and while the routing is working and displaying the selected tab, the smooth animation of navigating between tabs is no longer working. How can I use react router with Material-UI tabs to keep the tab animations working as they should?

As of now, I have the tabs in my HomeHeader.js and I am using this component to pass down the vale as props in order to change the value and thus change the selected tab.

For simplicity, I simplified my code to show the tabs I want to be linked.

Here is my code:

Header.js (Component with Tabs):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class HomeHeader extends Component {

  state = {
    value: false
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, value } = this.props

    return (
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar} elevation={this.props.elevation}>
          <Hidden smDown>
            <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="center">
              <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <Tab label="monitor" component={Link} to="/monitor" />
                <Tab label="sensor" component={Link} to="/sensor" />
              </Tabs>
            </Grid>
          </Hidden>
        </AppBar>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(HomeHeader)
```

Tab 1 Component (pass value into HomeHeader.js as props):

```
import React from 'react'

import HomeHeader from '../components/HomeHeader'

class SensorProductPage extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomeHeader value={1} />
        <div> Hello </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SensorProductPage
```

Tab 2 Component (pass value into HomeHeader.js as props):

```
import React from 'react'

import HomeHeader from '../components/HomeHeader'

class MonitorProductPage extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomeHeader value={0} />
        <div> Hello </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MonitorProductPage
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way you are using Routes here are inefficient.

It should be Tabs are implemented in one place and only one place as this (simply no need to use HomeHeader in every page):

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          fullWidth
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" component={Link} to="/one" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" component={Link} to="/two" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/one" component={PageShell(ItemOne)} />
        <Route path="/two" component={PageShell(ItemTwo)} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

as you can see tabs are asking for link and routes in the switch render compnents

for the animation I used this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/routes-animation-transitions-in-react-router-v4-9f4788deb964

here they are using **react-addons-css-transition-group**

please find the animation index.css file in demo

I wrapped pages from a HOC to make routing easier ( PageShell componet)

here is a working example:https://codesandbox.io/s/04p1v46qww

hope this will give you a head start

Comment: This isn't perfect unfortunately. If you load `/two` directly though the address bar without clicking on a tab, `Item One` is the tab highlighted, but it's the second tab that is actually displayed. This is quite challenging to solve actually.

Comment: @user8808265 agreed, it's challenging. anyone got a solution?

Comment: @Nadun,  The sandbox code does not meet the requirements. If you load page 2, then the Tab for page 1 is shown as active.

Answer (score 9):

To track active tab you can use location as tab value. And use router location as value for Tabs component. This way you achive change tabs animation out of box and highlight active tab when load page directly.

```
export const Module: React.FC<IModuleProps> = props => {
    const match = useRouteMatch();
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <>
            <Tabs value={location.pathname} >
                <Tab label="Dashboard" component={Link} to={`${match.url}/dashboard`} value={`${match.url}/dashboard`} />
                <Tab label="Audit Results" component={Link} to={`${match.url}/audit-results`} value={`${match.url}/audit-results`} />
            </Tabs>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`}>
                    <Dashboard />
                </Route>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/audit-results`}>
                    <AuditResults />
                </Route>
                <Route path={`${match.url}`}>
                    <Dashboard />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As for the current structure above you can see that the "tabs" are getting re-rendered with the change of the routes.

The way react is built by components holding components, so if you change one component, all of its children will get rendered.

So in your case, this is how the components are structures:

```
MainApp >
          Route('monitor') > MonitorProductPage > HomeHeader
          Route('sensor') > SensorProductPage > HomeHeader
```

You can see in this example, as you change a route you change all the content and need to re-render a NEW `HomeHeader`.

The way, I'll structure it for making sure `HomeHeader` will get created once and only props will change. (both for performance and for the issue here) 
Is like this:

```
MainApp >
          Route('innerpage/*') > InnerPage > 

               > MonitorProductPage
               > SensorProductPage
```

like this code in react router dom
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

That means you have a single route that will catch those inner pages, it could be like the above, or catch all (*)
Then you will have another router inside InnerPage that will decide which page to show.

```
const routes = [
{
    path: "/innerpage",
    component: InnerPage
  },
  {
    path: "/monitor",
    component: MonitorProductPage,
  },
  {
    path: "/sensor",
    component: SensorProductPage
  }
];
```

and Component "InnerPage" will render `HomeHeader` and inside it will have the router that will decide of its "body"