# React Router with Material UI tabs as Links

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am fairly new at programming in React and have come across something that has stumped me. I have been stuck on this thing for a couple of days now and I have a feeling I'm overlooking something.

Basically, I have tabs that have a link and load a component. But my issue is that the active tab is not changing accordingly. It resets back to the home tab, then if you click the same tab again, the active tab will show correctly. Kind of hard to explain, so I included all my simplified code in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-jones-b4sub?file=/src/header.js). If you were to start at the about me tab, then click the portfolio tab, it resets back to home but loads the portfolio component. Then if you click the portfolio tab again, it sets the active tab to it, which is correct.

I believe the issue is in the header.js file, and it has to do with the effect hook being reset/not being set properly. I tried using a use effect hook but had no luck, and wasn't sure if it really applied in this case. I looked for solutions for some time and found something similar here:
[How do you get Material-UI Tabs to work with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257426/how-do-you-get-material-ui-tabs-to-work-with-react-router)
However, this didn't solve my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that `Header` is being re-mounted (rather than just re-rendered) whenever you change tabs (so `value` is reset to `0`) because it is a child of a different component type (`Home` vs. `AboutMe` vs. `Portfolio`). The main options are: 1. render `Header` within `App` rather than the 3 sub-components; 2. Pull the state for the selected tab up to `App`; 3. Use the current path to control the current tab rather than separate state.

Comment: Knew I was overlooking something. This makes a lot more sense, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment Ryan left on the post, I made it so the header is re-mouned instead of being re-rendered on each page. By moving the header tag up to the App.js level I was able to solve the issue.